# Comment doit-on utiliser le futur antérieur ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, conjugaison, temps-grammatical

Le futur antérieur (aussi nommé « passé ») est une forme de verbe que je n'ai jamais vu utilisée, mais c'est répertorié dans les conjugaisons des verbes français. Par exemple, voici le futur antérieur du verbe *espérer* :

> j’aurai espéré
>   tu auras espéré
>   il/elle/on aura espéré
>   nous aurons espéré
>   vous aurez espéré
>   ils/elles auront espéré

Comment doit-on utiliser cette forme de  verbe, et pour communiquer quel sens ?  Est-elle souvent utilisée en français parlé, ou est-elle plus poétique ?

Comment: Edited to remove the 'imperatif'; it seems I inserted that incorrectly.  I'm just looking at the *futur antérieur*.

Comment: I think it's used about as much as in English. You didn't pick the most common verb, *I will have hoped* is indeed unusual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est une forme utilisée pour marquer que l'action aura lieu dans le futur mais avant un instant mentionné explicitement, souvent par une autre proposition.

> Tu auras fini de ranger avant que papa n'arrive.

---

La question originale faisait référence à l'impératif passé.  J'avais alors répondu :

> Aie fini de ranger avant que papa n'arrive.

C'est un peu soutenu (on dira plutôt « Si tu n'as pas fini de ranger avant que papa n'arrive, ... ») mais à mon oreille toujours possible en français parlé sans affectation.  Ce qui la rend rare c'est plutôt qu'il ne s'emploie <strike>que dans des phrases composées de deux propositions</strike> *qu'avec une indication de l'instant avant lequel on veut que l'ordre soit exécuté*.

Comment: Wiktionary dit que l'impératif futur antérieur pour *finir* est *aurez fini...* ?

Comment: à la deuxième personne du pluriel oui

Comment: "aurez fini"? je suis pratiquement certain que ce n'est pas un impératif. "ayez fini", peut-être?

Comment: Grevisse dit « ayez fini ».

Comment: "aurez fini" est de l'indicatif, "ayez fini" est de l’impératif.

Comment: L'exemple était pour le futur antérieur, mais pour l'impératif passé ça marche aussi en fait « Aie fini le projet demain ! ». Ça sonne quand même un peu cru sans introduction préalable.

Comment: Deux questions: (1) S'il ne fallait pas utiliser le subjonctif dans ton exemple, serait-il incorrect d'utiliser le passé composé pour la deuxième partie au lieu du subjonctif ou du futur simple ? (2) Si le sujet des deux parties de la phrase étaient les mêmes, serait-il possible de reformuler l'usage du futur antérieur (dans certains cas) en l'évitant comme ça : "Je te téléphonerai après avoir mangé" (au lieu de "Je te téléphonerai dès que j'aurai mangé" ?

Comment: @bronxbomber92, 1/ je ne comprends pas la question. 2/ Oui.

Answer (score 5):

> Comment doit-on utiliser cette forme de verbe, et pour communiquer quel sens ?

Pour indiquer qu'une action sera finie plus tard (d'où le passé), mais qu'elle ne l'est pas encore (d'où le futur).

> Est-elle souvent utilisée en français parlé, ou est-elle plus poétique ?

C'est très utilisé, oui !
Quelques exemples :

> - J'*aurai fini* mes devoirs dans une heure
> - Ils sortiront quand ils *auront reçu* l'autorisation.
> - Nous verrons ce film quand il *sera sorti* en DVD.
> - Pour indiquer qu'une action *sera finie* plus tard (d'où le passé), mais qu'elle ne l'est pas encore (d'où le futur).

Comment: « Pour indiquer qu'une action **sera finie** plus tard ». Il faut donc comprendre ce qu'est le futur antérieur pour… comprendre ce qu'est le futur antérieur ? :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - un peu comme un dictionnaire, où il faut comprendre le sens des mots pour pouvoir comprendre le sens des mots.

Answer (score 4):

Les réponses donnent déjà d'excellentes informations, je m'y associe.
Anecdotiquement, il y a un autre usage du futur antérieur, grammaticalement équivalent mais véhiculant **une notion de probabilité ou d'incertitude**, pour indiquer qu'on fait une supposition sur un événement situé dans le passé. Cet usage, bien connu notamment des fans de Tintin car Hergé en a usé (et abusé ?) est du type :

> Le professeur n'est plus là ?! Il aura sans doute pris un taxi*.

*(* exemple reconstitué de mémoire, à remplacer par une référence précise.)*

Answer (score 3):

Ah c'est un exercice amusant d'expliquer l'usage d'un temps qui n'est pas présent dans une autre langue !

Le *futur antérieur* porte la notion de passé dans le futur, pour situer un évènement comme antérieur à un autre.

*"Je te téléphonerai dès que j'aurai mangé." ("I will call you when I am done eating.")*

Les actions de *téléphoner* (futur simple) et de *manger* (futur antérieur) sont toutes les deux dans le futur, mais la phrase insiste sur le faire que celle de *mangé* est antérieure.

*"Il aura fini le projet demain." ("He will have finished this project by tomorrow.")*

Demain, l'action de *finir* (futur antérieur) sera du passé : on pourra alors dire *"Il a fini le projet."*

Ce n'est pas une de ces constructions anciennes qu'on ne trouve plus qu'à l'écrit ou dans un niveau de langage soutenu : l'utilisation familière dans le langage parlé est courante.