# si + futur antérieur

Tags: conjugaison, conditions, futur

Les phrases suivantes sont-elles correctes ? Quel est le niveau de langue ?

> Je me présenterai au concours en 2018 si je suis prêt.

(Si je suis prêt au moment du concours en 2018.) Usage du présent avec `si`.

> Je me présenterai au concours en 2018 si j'aurai préparé sérieusement.

(Si j'ai bien préparé entre maintenant et le moment du concours.) Usage du futur antérieur avec `si`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La première phrase est correcte, le niveau de langue est courant.

La deuxième est incorrecte cependant. On ne peut utiliser le futur antérieur avec *si* que sous certaines conditions.

Un tableau récapitulant toutes les structures des phrases en "si" se trouve [ici](http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/propositionsavecsi.htm).

On constate que le seul cas où le futur antérieur est utilisé répond aux conditions suivantes :

- **Supposition possible**
- **Fait ou cause (propositions avec *si*) future**
- **Conséquence (proposition principale) future**

La structure de la phrase est la suivante :

> ***Si* + [présent de l'indicatif], [futur antérieur].**

Par exemple:

> *Demain, si je passe te voir, j'aurai déjà parlé avec tes parents.*

En outre, **il n'existe aucun cas où l'on utilise le futur antérieur dans le fait ou la cause** comme tu l'as fait dans ton exemple erroné.

Plus d'informations sur l'utilisation du futur antérieur sont données dans la réponse à cette question : [Comment doit-on utiliser le futur antérieur ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/681/comment-doit-on-utiliser-le-futur-ant%C3%A9rieur?rq=1)

Comment: Ça répond à la question, merci. Comment exprimer l'idée de succession des événements qui m'intéresse dans ce cas ?

Comment: Je pense que ta 1e phrase est une très bonne façon d'exprimer ce que tu veux. En effet, l'action "être prêt" est une action présente par rapport à l'événement futur "se présenter au concours". On pourrait clarifier en écrivant "je me présenterai au concours si je suis prêt à ce moment-là."