# L'utilisation de futur antérieur dans le passé

Tags: grammaire

Dans "Grammaire Essentielle B2 - CLE"

> On utilise le futur antérieur pour présenter:
>
> un fait qui est donné comme probable et situé dans le passé
>
> *Elle n'est pas rentrée : sa réunion aura duré plus longtemps que prévu*

Pourquoi on n'utilise pas le plus-que-parfait ici?

Comment: En attendant l'occasion de répondre, pour ce qui concerne la notion de probabilité, je trouve très utile cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2727/1893) par RomainValeri.

Answer (score 1):

On peut utiliser le futur antérieur pour exprimer l'idée de la probabilité ou une supposition quand l'explication de ce qui est arrivé n'est pas certaine ou la cause de l'événement est probable mais pas encore vérifiée. Quand on ne sait pas exactement ce qui s'est passé et on devine un peu la meilleure raison possible, on emploie le futur antérieur au lieu d'un temps au passé.

- Elle n'est pas rentrée : sa réunion aura duré plus longtemps que prévu. (Probablement elle n'est pas encore rentrée à cause de la réunion, mais on ne sait pas. Il est probable mais pas certain, c'est  imprévu.)

Par contre, le plus-que-parfait ou le passé composé indique ce qui s'est vraiment passé.

- Elle n'est pas rentrée parce que sa réunion avait duré plus longtemps que prévu.  (Et elle a téléphoné pour nous le dire.  C'est un fait.)

De la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4129#:%7E:text=Le%20futur%20ant%C3%A9rieur%20est%20un,aura%20mang%C3%A9%2C%20je%20serai%20sorti.) (mes explications entre parenthèses):

> Le futur antérieur [...] peut servir à exprimer, par rapport à un fait
> présent, une hypothèse ou une supposition qui peut expliquer ce fait.
> Dans cet emploi, le futur antérieur équivaut à un passé composé
> empreint d'une idée de possibilité.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Ils sont en retard; ils auront sans doute été retardés par un embouteillage. (Probablement c'est à cause de la circulation.
>   Peut-être ils étaient tous à la même réunion.)
> - J'aurai oublié mes clés au restaurant. Je ne les trouve plus. (C'est la meilleure hypothèse mais comme les clés sont perdues, je ne sais
>   pas.)

D'autres exemples ([réf](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-ii/french-ii-future-tenses/the-futur-anterieur)) montrent la traduction "must have" pour indiquer la probabilité :

> - Il n'est pas venu. Il aura oublié notre rendez‐vous. He didn't come.
>   He must have forgotten our appointment.
> - Elle est en retard. Il sera
>   arrivé quelque chose. She's late. Something must have happened.